# How do you generate a List of Lists from Long Strings in a DataFrame Column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

Have a very awkward setup. I have a DataFrame with long strings in the second column, which I want to break up and convert into a list of lists.

```
   col1  col2      
0  P     mary jane clare     
1  Q     tom dick harry     
2  R     sam jack bill
```

I'd like the following list of lists as output:

```
[["mary", "jane", "clare"],["tom", "dick", "harry"],["sam", "jack", "bill"]]
```

Very unsure how to approach this one.

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split col2 using white space and then apply the to_list() method to come up with a single list

```
df['col2'].str.split('\s').to_list()
```